# Is there a way to implicitly make an button be multi-line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want a button that is similar to this:

```
ONE
TWO
```

Where one word is over the other. However, it may be:

```
THREE
FOUR
```

Or any number, really. Is there a way with NSAttributedStrings that I can say to always have a line-break after the first word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not about `NSAttributedString` or `NSString`, but rather about the button itself. You may think of subclassing `UIButton` and overriding `setTitle:forState:` to automatically replace the first space with a `\n`.

Specifically the `setTitle:forState:` would look something like this

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state {
    NSRange firstSpaceRanger = [title rangeOfString:@" "];
    if (firstSpaceRanger.location != NSNotFound) {
        title = [title stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstSpaceRanger withString:@"\n"];
    }
    [super setTitle:title forState:state];
}
```

For instance, given `one two three` this will produce

```
one
two three
```

In order to make the button multiline you can do, in the `UIButton` initializer:

```
self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

---

<sub>Yes, `firstSpaceRanger` is intentional. I couldn't resist.</sub>